# PHP XPath xml file cdata error

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to get data from a XML file through xPath.

This is the XML:

```
<item>
    <title>
        51-årig stukket i maven: Klapper i over for politiet
    </title>
    <link>
        http://newsbreak.dk/51-aarig-ringede-om-hjaelp-efter-knivstik-nu-tier-han/
    </link>
    <pubDate>Tue, 20 Jan 2015 09:19:46 +0000</pubDate>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[
    <img width="600" height="400" src="http://newsbreak.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/politi44.jpg" class="attachment-big" alt="Foto: Colourbox (genrefoto)" /><br />51-årig mand vil ikke tale med politiet, selvom han selv ringede til ordensmagten for at få hjælp til knivstik
    ]]>
    </description>
    <category>
        <![CDATA[ A-historier ]]>
    </category>
    <category>
        <![CDATA[ Krim ]]>
    </category>
    <guid>
        http://newsbreak.dk/51-aarig-ringede-om-hjaelp-efter-knivstik-nu-tier-han/
    </guid>
</item>
```

This is the PHP:

```
$titelQuery = $xpath->query("//item/title/text()");
$itemQuery = $xpath->query("//item");
$linkQuery = $xpath->query("//item/guid/text()");
$imageQuery = $xpath->query("//item/description/text()");
```

I get the title and link correctly , but when im trying to get the "description" part, im only getting the text after the image tag like so:

```
<br />51-årig mand vil ikke tale med politiet, selvom han selv ringede til ordensmagten for at få hjælp til knivstik
]]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just target that `<description>` node, then use `->nodeValue`:

```
$imageQuery = $xpath->query("//item/description");
echo $imageQuery->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/q5uU7x)

Using `->evaluate()` will work as well:

```
echo $xpath->evaluate('string(//item/description)');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but im still getting the same output ,

Is it something with the xml file

http://newsbreak.dk/feed/

Comment: @PatrickLarsen no, the image tag is there, just right click -> inspect element, its there. i attached a demo on the answer.

Comment: I've pasted my code here, still getting same error: http://codepad.viper-7.com/UAqpLw

Comment: Thank you very much, marked your answer as correct :-)

Comment: @PatrickLarsen oh okay, anyways, the problematic line is `@$this->dom->loadHTML($html);`. since you're loading xml, this should be `@$this->dom->loadXML($html);` on your class. i don't know why you need (class) them though.